# HTML+CSS responsive DIV grid

Tags: html, css, width

I am working on a project for which I would like to have a responsive page with divs. It woudl look like a grid, and on small screens instead of having 3 column, the div would reorganize to go on 2 columns.

here is where i am with a simple html :

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="right-column">Php generated content</div>
    <div id="left-column">
        <div class="element">Article 1</div>
        <div class="element">Article 2</div>
        <div class="element">Article 3</div>
        <div class="element">Article 4</div>
        <div class="element">Article 5</div>
        <div class="element">Article 6</div>
        <div class="element">Article ...etc</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GeorgesL/1zdx735y/

It doesn't take the whole width after going on 2 columns and I may not have the competence to understand why...

Also, I have to precise that the Articles are actually pictures.
Thanks a lot :)

Lucas

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly you will need to

1. Manage the width of wrapper div for different breakpoints
2. Use `float:left;` for `.element`

Apart from this here are basic three breal-points used commonly specific to  which you will to write your css.

```
@media screen and (max-width:959px){

}
@media screen and (max-width:640px){

}
@media screen and (max-width:320px){

}
```

**Please note:**

1. Purposefully I have not added any CSS under breakpoint - which would be best if you could try it on your own.
2. You may use few more breal-points as well specific to various device sizes.